# PSD to html conversion

Tags: html, css, psd, 960.gs

I have completed designing the template in photoshop. now i want to convert it into html although i am very well aware of all the html, css javascript elements i use firebug too , i have converted many templates till date. my codes does not comprise of the quality it needs. when i download any templates from some premium sites and look onto their codes i feel my code is very bad in shape, my codes crave for improvement. i want to master the proper use of div , ul and li elements, and the css.

is their any proper resource on the web that could teach me how i do it?

is it good if i use 960gs framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) provides a layout for quick coding of pages, although you'll need to go through it and pick out what you don't need.

[Line25](http://line25.com/) has a lot of tips on coding sites, including a tutorial on [converting from PSD to HTML](http://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-convert-a-photoshop-mockup-to-xhtml-css), and [Soh Tanaka](http://www.sohtanaka.com/)'s site also has a lot of tutorials.

Answer (score 3):

My Bible: [A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Such resources as [bestpsdtohtml.com](http://www.bestpsdtohtml.com) can be useful too

Answer (score 0):

[css-tricks](http://css-tricks.com/) is another great resource and has some free video content demonstrating converting a photoshop mock up into html and css.
I think [this is the first of three](http://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/71-building-a-website-photoshop-mockup/) showing the end to end process.